# Trigger event after input field value is changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am using JSF, RichFaces and JavaScript. I change the value of an input field by JavaScript and after such a change, I want to trigger an event. My first try was to use this code:

```
<t:inputText id="info" value="#{controller.state}" onchange="adaptUserInterface();" />
```

Unfortunately 'onchange' didn't get triggered. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can use this: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Comment: You want to call a js function on text change ? know that the change event will be called when your input will loose its focus (click outside it for example)

Answer (score 1):

Use [onBlur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp). That should be enough for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onKeyup` for changes and `onPaste` and `onInput` for pasted content in Textfields.

```
(function() {
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
    info.addEventListener('keyUp', function(){ adaptUserInterface(info.value)} );
    info.addEventListener('paste', function(){ adaptUserInterface(info.value)} );
    info.addEventListener('input', function(){ adaptUserInterface(info.value)} );
})();

function adaptUserInterface(value){  
  console.log(value);
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGrDd)